# bit shifting - keep value as a byte

Tags: c#, byte, bit-shift

Suppose I had the following byte:

```
 byte myByte = 0xff; // 1111 1111 eg 255
```

and I want to shift 2 bits to the left:

```
 int newNumber = myByte << 2;
```

`newNumber` is `0011 1111 1100` e.g. 1020

My question is, how do I drop the 2 most significant bits? My expected value would be 252 `1111 1100`.

I asked the question because I am currently doing some AVR programming and interested in how this is done in C#.

Comment: `(myByte << 2) & 0xFF`

Comment: @MarcB: `&&` is a logical operator, not a bitwise one.

Comment: @MarcB - `(myByte << 2) & 0xFF` returns a `Int32`

Comment: yes, because you're  doing `int newNumber`. The compiler is doing exactly what you told it to. the & 0xFF will simply mask off bits 8->15, so you still only have 8 useful bits (0->7) in the value

Comment: Yes you are correct - I didn't mention in the OP that I want a `byte` returned. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int newNumber = ((byte)(myByte << 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the result to a byte.  That ought to do it.

Or:

```
var result = newNumber & 0xFF
```

Comment: The 2nd answer still produces an `int`, only the value is byte-ranged.

Comment: I was merely addressing the OP's request to lop off the two high-order bits.